# How to identify document categories like Movie or Biography

Tags: machine-learning, naivebayes, supervised-learning, document-classification

I am currently running a task of categorizing some documents into some pre-defined sets of classes. For this, I am relying on Multinomial Naive Bayes, and it works fine for most categories like baseball, sports or space.

However, how do I find out articles of categories like movies or biography of some person? MNB primarily runs on bag of words jargon approach. That is why it is easy to detect baseball articles, because they will contain lots of baseball jargon. However, movie or biography articles contain very less jargon. Movie documents describe the movie, or review it, with words specific to that movie only. So an article about A Few Good Men may contain lots of legal terms, which may lead to inadvertently labeling it as "Law". Same for biographies, it just describes the life of a person.

How to classify such kind of documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good solution is to use **Named Entity Recognition** and **Semi supervised approach**. For example you tagged name of actors in a sentences(With Entity Extraction semi supervised methods, check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition)), and get count of specific entity(e.g: the more the count of actors(our entity) repeated in a sentence, the more the sentence is related to movies). Then add it to a feature, so it might be representative and important for classifier, try to find such these features from your data sets and feed your classifier with these

You can check the effectiveness and impact of any added feature with measurement like [Chi2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html) or [ANOVA F Value](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif.html)

Comment: I have thought about it. Problem is, there are a million (and constantly counting) actors and actresses, how do I find out that the named entity is being used in the context of acting? Sometimes the actor and character's names are used alternately, which adds to the problem.

Comment: To use semi supervised approaches, you need databases for actor names or characters associated to actors, try to find data sets as much as you can in online api and databases

Comment: Ah, right, I was fearing as much. The problem is, there are several categories like that. Movies, history, geography, music..the list is endless!

Comment: Not to mention, this will not even work accurately even if done. For example, an article on A Few Good Men will mention the names of Tom Cruise or Jack Nicholson only once, the remainder will contain their character names. On basis of just one occurrence from the database, obviously I cannot label it as movie, that will mean Scientology articles containing Tom Cruise will also be mapped as movies. So we have to first map Tom Cruise to his character name in the article, then treat all uses of that character name as Tom Cruise, and similarly for others Then perhaps it will come close.. :(